# ASP.NET MVC: use of @ in C# code block

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper

I'm a little bit confused with the use of @. In the following code I first wrote `Html.ActionLink(...)` instead of `@Html.ActionLink(...)` because I was in a `if` block (C# code). So, I would like to understand exactly when I do have to use @ and when I don´t have to use it.

```
<td width="32%" align="center">
     @if (Model.SeccionImpresos != null)
     {
           @Html.ActionLink("IMPRESOS", "Index", "Trabajo", null, null, "#impresos", new { id = Model.Id }, null);
     }
</td>
```

I appreaciate any help on this.

Comment: http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`@` has two uses:

- It's used to start a code *block* (`@if`, `@foreach`, @{ ... }, etc) from a markup context (as opposed to from another code block)
- It's used for code *nuggets* – expressions which are written to the output stream (`@expression`).

Writing `Html.ActionLink` without `@` in a code block creates a normal method call that discards its result.