# Viewbag.title like "String Title"+@model.name is it possible?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, viewbag, page-title

I want make page title like "Index-'CategoryName'".I tried use codes like this:

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<Article>
@using PagedList.Mvc;
@using PagedList;

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index"+@Model.Category.Name;
}
```

but it didn't work. How can i make page title like "Index-C#" ?? What should i use?

Comment: You should try to understand the reason for this behaviour. Take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10321902/asp-net-mvc-use-of-in-c-sharp-code-block

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should reference your model as just `Model`, not `@Model`. The `@` character is used in order to start writing code when you are in the middle of the HTML markup, but in this case you are already inside a code block (started with `@{` in the previous line).

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
 ViewBag.Title = "Index" + Model.Category.Name;
```

Answer (score 2):

Just like this:

```
ViewBag.Title = "Index" + Model.Category.Name;
```

Without the @.

Here are some links helping you to understand when/where to use @:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-s-and-lt-text-gt-syntax

http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2013/01/09/ten-tricks-for-razor-views.aspx